# How Can i make the particles stationary as they are in Frame 1

Tags: particles

I have attached a blend file (not made by me) of a galaxy made from particles. I want the galaxy to look like and stay as it is in the Frame No. 1. How can i stop the particles as the timeline moves so that the galaxy retains the shape and particles dont move. I have tried making the "ALL" and "GRAVITY" in forces to zero for all particle systems, but it doesnt help.

I want the galaxy to be static and move a camera from far into the galaxy. Hence need it to be stationary. Please help.

https://easyupload.io/dj9nbw

Answer (score 0):

All your particle systems have the default velocity settings, which is 1 m/s in *Normal* direction. Of course they move - you have to set them all to 0 m/s or even better, set *Physics* to *None* instead of *Newtonian*, then you don't have to disable *Gravity* or *All* forces.

Another thing I noticed is that all particles have a lifetime of 50, which means (since they are all spawned on frame 1), after frame 50 they will disappear (your animation end frame is set to 250), because under *Render > Extras* you haven't enabled *Dead*.

This is also a way to have them not move or react to forces: Set lifetime just to 1 and enable the option to render *Dead* particles. Then they stay where they were born but still show in render.

Here's an overview of the settings I mention which you could / should change:

[image: particle settings]